# .net 3.5 databind and nhibernate 3.3

Tags: .net, nhibernate

This may be kind of a strange question, but maybe somebody has an idea...

I just completed and upgrade of NHibernate 1.2 to 3.3. The upgrade went fairly well and everything seems to be working correctly except when I try to databind an IList of objects to either a DropDown or GridView. Basically what happens is that if the list is large the .DataBind call takes a very long time, often causing the application to time out.

I'm sure the issue has to do with binding large lists, but it seems strange that the issue wasn't happening before the nhibernate upgrade. For example the following code was unchanged during the upgrade:

```
MarketSourceLogic sourceLogic = new MarketSourceLogic();
ddl = ((DropDownList)Accordion1.FindControl("dEditSourceAbbr"));
ddl.DataSource = sourceLogic.LoadAllMarketSources();
ddl.DataTextField = "Abbr";
ddl.DataValueField = "MarketSourceId";
ddl.DataBind();
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(Constants.DROPDOWN_SELECT_TEXT, "0"));
```

With NHib 1.2 the code took several seconds to execute (especially the LoadAllMarketSources call) but would render without a problem.
After the upgrade to 3.3 the LoadAllMarketSources call took about the same amount of time but once ddl.DataBind() was called the page just kind of hung and eventually timed out.

I know it's not the best way to load a drop down by getting the entire list of objects, I should just get the fields I need. That's not the point this is just an example. The problem also occurs when loading a gridview where I need the entire object. The real problem is that many of these grids are loaded with search results and the user has the option of not searching on anything and so the page will time out.

Basically I would like to know if there is a way around this issue of time outs (maybe I'm missing an NHibernate setting?) or if the whole project needs refactored.

Any help and insight is appreciated.

Please note I did try with .net 4 and get the same results.

Comment: This looks to me like an issue with Lazy Loading. Maybe you are triggering Select N+1 while loading the list in a dropdown. Try to see what SQL statements it generates with SQL Server Profiler (if SQL Server database is used) or NH Prof.

Comment: It looks like it is the lazy loading issue. However I am curious as to why the child objects are being loaded. In the example Abbr is a string and MarketSourceId is an int. Maybe I am misunderstanding lazy loading, but I thought that the child objects should only be loaded when they are accessed i.e. parent.child would load the child and the child is not in memory until that call. Why would databind force all the child objects to load?

Comment: You are right... it should trigger loading only when you try to access it. Check if there is something else that could trigger loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `.DataBind()` was calling `GetHashCode()` which was forcing the child object to load. Just needed to modify `GetHashCode()` in order to avoid loading the child object. Many thanks to Miroslav for the helpful comments.